# Sending email attchment from form

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment from a form within my meteor app. Sending the email is fine, it works, however, I'm at a loss as to how I send the attachment. My form gives the user the ability to attach a file, however, I can't figure out how I pass it to the server to send as an attachment.

I've looked at the meteor [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html) and it's not that helpful.

It points to [mailcompser 4](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/blob/v4.0.1/README.md#attachments).

When I console.log attachments on the server the name appears. It says it needs a path, however, I have no idea what that is.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Path: `client`

```
class EmailForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };

    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const errors = jobApplicationValidation(this.state);

    const attachments = [
      {
        fileName: this.fileInput.current.files[0].name,
      },
    ];

    const attachments = [];

    attachments.push(this.fileInput.current.files[0]);

    Meteor.call(
      'sendEmail',
      this.props.email,
      this.props.myEmail,
      this.props.subject,
      this.props.text,
      this.fileInput.current.files[0],
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={this.fileInput}
        />
        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Apply</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Server`

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendJobApplicationEmail(to, from, subject, text, attachments) {
      // Make sure that all arguments are strings.
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    this.unblock();

    Email.send({ to, from, subject, text, attachments });
  },
});
```

Comment: Uploading files is not as trivial as one might think. I can recommend `ostrio:files` to upload files to a non files system target on your server. Once uploaded you can send the mail with the attachment and on success you can delete the uploaded binary or keep it in a virtual send folder

Comment: I recommend upload file to file storage like Amazon S3 and then send the attachment by URL. S3 support private links to prevent the file to be accessed by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Willson to the rescue:

> Meteor’s default email package 3 uses mailcomposer 14 behind the
> scenes. Make sure your attachments array follows the options listed in
> mailcomposer’s attachment docs 40. In your example you’re referencing
> a PDF, so you’ll likely want your attachments array to look something
> like:

```
 ... attachments: [   {
     fileName: 'book.pdf',
     filePath: '/home/hexen/Downloads/book.pdf',   }, ]
```

https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-email-with-attachment/23026

But our fellow buddies in the comments are correct, you need a way to upload those files to the server and `ostrio:files` is one of the best packages out there.

Here's an example within our application to guide you along the way:

```
MailQueue.sendMail({
            to: payslip.employee.email,
            from: 'Payroll System <no-reply@example.com>',
            subject: `Payslip of ${payslip.payrollDate}`,
            html: `Hello ${payslip.employee.full_name}, <br /><br />Here is your payslip for payroll of ${payslip.payrollDate}<br /><br />Thanks.`,
            attachments: [{ path: `'/tmp/${payslip.employee.full_name}.zip'` }],
          });
```

First off, we're relying on [Meteor Mailer](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Mailer) as it allows us to customize mail sending options (it's ok, you don't have to use it). We create our files on the server, stored in `/tmp/` directory.